# Is there a way to get the FULL location of a substring inside of another string?

Tags: python

So i want to make it so this sort of thing would happen:

```
print(locate("Hello world!", "world!"))
returns: 6 11
```

So you could use it in locating a FULL phrase instead of just the first letter with `x.index("Hello!")`

Comment: Add the length of substring to first position and subtract one to find position of last character of substring in string.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the length of the substring to the matched index

```
def locate(full, sub):
    index = full.index(sub)
    return index, index + len(sub)
```

For example

```
>>> locate("Hello world!", "world!")
(6, 12)
```

You can use this for slicing back into the original string

```
>>> s = "Hello world!"
>>> start, end = locate(s, "world!")
>>> s[start:end]
'world!'
```

Note that `str.index` raises a `ValueError` if the substring is not found.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity (and because it would help my programming lol) is there a way to find the nth time x is mentioned, like eg:
```x = "Hello my name is John, Hello john, Hello!"
x.index("Hello", 2)```
To find the second instance of the word Hello

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex-

```
import re
r = re.compile("world")
match = r.search("Hello world!")
print(match.span())
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def locate(string, key):
    start = string.index(key)
    return start, start+len(key)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! When you answer a question you should include some kind of explanation, like what the author did wrong and what you did to fix it. I'm telling you this because your answer has been flagged as low-quality and is currently being reviewed. You can [edit] your answer by clicking the "Edit" button.